# Probability for finding a double-as-likely event

Tags: probability, approximation

Repeating an experiment with $n$ possible outcomes $t$ times independently, where all but one outcomes have probability $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and the other outcome has the double probability $\frac{2}{n+1}$, is there a good approximate formula for the probability that the outcome with the higher probability happens more often than any other one?

For me, $n$ is typically some hundreds, and $t$ is chosen depending on $n$ such that the probability that the most likely outcome occurs most often is between 10% and 99.999%.

In the moment I use a small program that calculates a crude approximation by assuming that the counts for how often each outcome shows up in $t$ trials are independent and approximate the counts using the Poisson distribution. How can I improve on this?

**EDIT:** I'd strongly appreciate comments/votes on the two (maybe soon more) answers given.

**EDIT 2:** As none of the two answers is convincing me, but as I don't want to let the 100 points bounty to vanish (and as nobody voted for/against one of the two answers), I'll just pick one of the answers. I'd still appreciate other answers.

Comment: With large `n` the independent Poisson approximation is probably fine. Did you try simulation studies of how well the formula is working?

Comment: This question is closely related to the Generalized Birthday Problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @Aniko: I haven't run extensive simulations yet. But the examples I tried are roughly correct.

Comment: @Charles: In which sense are they related? Can you please elaborate on it? I see only a very vague connection and would be happy to understand it better.

Comment: The central difficulty in your problem (and in the birthday problem) is the difficulty of determining the distribution of the maximum (supremum norm) of a multinomial random variable, which involves summing over partitions.

Comment: @pul, Some questions: When you say "more often than any other one" do you mean there are *strictly* more counts for the double-probability outcome than all others or *at least as many* as the maximum number of counts over the other outcomes? Is the approximation you're using that you have a sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n+1}$ of independent Poisson r.v.'s where $\lambda_1 = 2t/(n+1)$ and $\lambda_i = t/(n+1)$ for $2 \leq i \leq n+1$? Or some other model? I just want to make sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @cardinal: With "more often" I meant "strictly", but I would be content also with "as many or more". I have only $n$ random variables in total, but otherwise your model is correct.

Comment: @charles: The birthday paradox as I know it looks only for the probability that max >= 2. But I'll take a look, if I can find something more general using this term.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thanks for catching that typo. With the other $n+1$'s running around, it naturally slipped out as I was typing. The other reason that could have happened was due to the way I was thinking of the model. An equivalent one is to consider $n+1$ outcomes of equal probability and ask what the chance is that the sum of the first two is greater than each of the remaining individual counts. From there, I was hoping I could take advantage of some symmetry considerations.

Comment: The Poisson model is a good start and I can give you an immediate exponential bound in that case. Since the problem you consider is a conditional form of the Poisson model, then we should be able to connect the two that way.

Comment: I've found out that the probability for a specific $t$ is a rational polynomial in $n$. The first few are: $2/(n+1)$, $4/(n+1)^2$, $4(3n-1)/(n+1)^3$, $8(3n^2-5n+4)/(n+1)^4$, $8(5n^3-20n^2+45n-26)/(n+1)^5$, $4(15n^4-110n^3+465n^2-742n+388)/(n+1)^6$, $4(21n^5-245n^4+1645n^3-4837n^2+6440n-2992)/(n+1)^7$, $16(7n^6-119n^5+1155n^4-5313n^3+12544n^2-14230n+5972)/(n+1)^8$. Haven't found a way to generalise this for arbitrary $t$, though.

Comment: @Thies: Thanks for the effort. Could you please post your comment with proof idea as an answer. If nothing better shows up in the next 5 hours ....

Comment: @Thies, note that the $p_i$ here are all rational with least common denominator of $n+1$. So, of course, in a sample of size $t$, *any* probability of a multinomial of this type will be rational with denominator $(n+1)^t$.

Comment: @cardinal: sure, the $/(n+1)^t$ part is kind of a given. But i didn't expect to find a polynomial of $(t-2)$th order in $n$ for the nominator part that is consistent with every $n$ i checked so far. Perhaps someone can shed some light on why it should look like this?

Comment: @Thies, it's not of order $t-2$ for $t=1$. :) But, more seriously, your point about the numerator is a bit more interesting. There is a lot of symmetry in this problem, so it doesn't strike me a shocking on the surface.

Comment: @cardinal: Why don't you post your exponential bound. Within the next 2 hours I'll pick the best available answer...

Comment: @pul: It really only works well for [$t = \Omega(n \log n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) and I'm not sure that case is particularly interesting to you.

Comment: @cardinal: What probabilities for the more likely one to be first do get for such $t$? (And what would you comment to leonbloy's answer?)

Comment: A hard bound on the Poisson model is as follows. Let $Z_1 \sim \mathrm{Poi}(2t/(n+1))$ and $Z_i \sim \mathrm{Poi}(t/(n+1))$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$. All the $Z_i$ are mutually independent. Then $\mathbb{P}(Z_1 > \max_{i\geq 2} Z_i) \geq 1 - (n-1) \exp(-c t / (n+1))$ where $c = (\sqrt{2}-1)^2$. As you can see, it only works well for $t \geq 6 n \log n$ or so.

Comment: @cardinal: Are you sure about your approximate formula? I just looked at some value (with t big enough) and didn't get reasonable results.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of the bound in the Poisson case. Can you give me a couple of pairs $(n,t)$ of test values?

Comment: @cardinal: Sorry, I had a bug. The results are now reasonable, but not very good. For $n = 199$ and $t = 8115$ I get 99% success with my approximation and your estimate gives >=81.7% (where $6n \log n = 6320$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partition the outcomes by the frequency of occurrences $x$ of the "double outcome", $0 \le x \le t$.  Conditional on this number, the distribution of the remaining $t-x$ outcomes is multinomial across $n-1$ *equiprobable* bins.  Let $p(t-x, n-1, x)$ be the chance that no bin out of $n-1$ equally likely ones receives more than $x$ outcomes.  The sought-for probability therefore equals

$$\sum_{x=0}^{t} \binom{t}{x}\left(\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^x \left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{t-x} p(t-x,n-1,x).$$

In [Exact Tail Probabilities and Percentiles of the Multinomial Maximum](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/mult.pdf), Anirban DasGupta points out (after correcting typographical errors) that $p(n,K,x)K^n/n!$ equals the coefficient of $\lambda^n$ in the expansion of $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{x}\lambda^j/j!\right)^K$ (using his notation).  For the values of $t$ and $n$ involved here, this coefficient can be computed in at most a few seconds (making sure to discard all $O(\lambda^{n+1})$ terms while performing the successive convolutions needed to obtain the $K^{\text{th}}$ power).  (I checked the timing and corrected the typos by reproducing DasGupta's Table 4, which displays the complementary probabilities $1 - p(n,K,x)$, and extending it to values where $n$ and $K$ are both in the hundreds.)

Quoting a theorem of Kolchin *et al.*, DasGupta provides an approximation for the computationally intensive case where $t$ is substantially larger than $n$.  Between the exact computation and the approximation, it looks like all possibilities are covered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Looks very good, but I have to check the details. What do you mean with "I ... corrected the typos by reproducing DasGupta's Table 4, ..."? (By the way, if you had answered 2-3 hours earlier, you'd save me some headaches about what to do with my bounty.)

Comment: @pul His inequalities are in the wrong direction: what he claims are $p(n,K,x)$ are really $1 - p(n,K,x-1)$.  Sorry about the bounty problem: I knew how to answer this one when it first appeared but needed to check the results first and had no time to do anything about it until the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with some comments, in that the Poisson approximation sounds nice here (not a 'crude' approximation). It should be asympotically exact, and it seems the most reasonable thing to do, as an exact analytic solutions seems difficult.

As an intermediate alternative, (if you really need it) I suggest I fisrt order correction to the Poisson approximation, in the following way (I've done something similar some time ago, and it worked).

As suggested by a comment, your model is (not approximately but exactly) Poisson if we condition on the sum. That is:

Let $X_t$ ($t$ is a parameter here) be a vector of $n$ independent Poisson variables, the first one with $\lambda = 2t/(n+1)$, the others with $\lambda = t/(n+1)$. Let $s=\sum x$, so $E(s)=t$. It is clear that $X_t$ is not equivalent to other model (because our model is restricted to $s=t$), but it is a good approximation. Further, the distribution of $X_t | s$ is equivalent to our model. Indeed, we can write

$ \displaystyle P(X_t) = \sum_s P(X_t | s) P(s)$

This can also be writen for the event in consideration (that $x_1 $ is the maximum).

We know to compute the LHS, and $P(s)$, but we are interested in the other term. Our first order Poisson approximation comes from assuming that $P(s)$ concentrates about the mean so that it can be assimilated to a delta, and then $ P(X_t) \approx  P(X_t | s=t) $

To refine the aprroximation, we can see the above as a convolution of two functions: our unknown $P(X_t | s)$, which we assume smooth around $s=t$, and a quasi delta function, say a gaussian with small variance. Now, we have our first order approximation (for continuous variables) :

$h(x) = g(x)  * N(x_0,\sigma^2)$ (convolution)

$h(x_0) \approx g(x_0)  + g(x_0)''\sigma^2/2$

$g(x_0) \approx h(x_0)  - h''(x_0)''\sigma^2/2$

Applying this to the previous equation can lead to a refined approximation to our desired probability.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to find $\sigma^2$?

Comment: $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $s$, which is the sum of $n$ independent poisson

Comment: @leonbloy: OK, in our case we have therefore $\sigma^2 = t$ (thanks!). And how do I get h"?

Comment: I'd approximate the second derivative by the second difference : $A_{t+1}-2A_t+A{t-1}$, the probability of  your 'success' event evaluated at different values of $t$

Comment: @leonbloy: I'm not really convinced of your answer (yet???), but before letting the bounty points vanish into nowhere, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not fully convinced myself, and I'm not after bounty points. You can very well accept this answer only when (if) you confirm it's correct-helpful. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of explanation: Part out of curiosity, part for lack of a better more theoretical method, i approached the problem in a completely empirical/inductive way. I'm aware that there is the risk of getting stuck in a dead end without gaining much insight, but i thought, i'll just present what i got so far anyway, in case it is useful to someone.

Starting by computing the exact probabilities for $n,t\in\{1,...,8\}$ we get

[image: Table of the first few probabilities for low n,t]

Due to the underlying multinomial distribution, multiplying the entries in the table by $(n+1)^t$ leaves us with a purely integer table:

[image: Table of integerified probabilities]

Now we find that there is a polynomial in $n$ for every column which acts as the sequence function for that column:

[image: Sequence functions for different t's]

Dividing the sequence functions by $(n+1)^t$ gives us sequence functions for the original probabilities for the first $t$'s. These rational polynomials can be simplified by decomposing them into partial fractions and substituting $x$ for $1/(n+1)$, leaving us with:

[image: Sequence functions in x=1/(n+1)]

or as coefficient table

[image: sequence function coefficients]

Starting with the $x^2$ column there are sequence functions for these coefficients again:

[image: x^k coefficients sequence functions]

That's how far i got. There are definitely exploitable patterns here that allow sequence functions to occur, but i'm not sure if there is a nice closed form solution for these sequence functions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'm not sure what your results imply for $n$ and $t$ in the hundreds.

Comment: I actually tried to approximate the probability for bigger $n,t$ by just taking the $x^2$ part of the series into account, but that only works for small probabilities, for the probabilities that you're interested in, the approximation is way off.

Comment: I'm not convinced of neither your answer (as small $n$ don't seem to help for the $n$'s I need) nor the other (as I don't understand (yet??) its correctness/helpfulness). As I have more hope to get something out of the other answer and as I don't want to let the 100 points vanish, I'll probably accept the other answer. Sorry for not picking yours!