# How to combine two independent repeated experiments with different success probabilities?

Tags: probability, sampling

Repeating an experiment ([about which I asked before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10407/probability-for-finding-a-double-as-likely-event)) with $n$ possible outcomes $t$ times independently, where all but one outcomes have probability $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and the other outcome has the double probability $\frac{2}{n+1}$, I also obtain an independent information where the outcome with double probability shows up 50% more likely than the other outcomes (i.e., with probability $\frac{3}{2n+1}$ and the others' probability is $\frac{2}{2n+1}$).

*How do I combine the two results?*

**Alternative formulation:** Given is the probability space $(\Omega\times\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega\times\Omega), \mathrm{p})$ with
$$\mathrm{p}(\omega, \omega') = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{6}{(n+1)(2n+1)} & \mbox{ if } \omega = \omega_0 \mbox{ and } \omega' = \omega_0\\
\frac{4}{(n+1)(2n+1)} & \mbox{ if } \omega = \omega_0 \mbox{ and } \omega' \ne \omega_0\\
\frac{3}{(n+1)(2n+1)} & \mbox{ if } \omega \ne \omega_0 \mbox{ and } \omega' = \omega_0\\
\frac{2}{(n+1)(2n+1)} & \mbox{ otherwise }
\end{array}\right.$$

where $\omega_0\in\Omega$ is unknown (and $|\Omega| = n$). The goal is to find $\omega_0$ given $t$ samples from $\Omega\times\Omega$.

Currently I'm counting how often each value shows up in the first coordinate and add the number of times it shows up in the second coordinate multiplied by a weighting factor of $\log_2(\frac{3}{2})$. The value with the highest number should be $\omega_0$ (if $t$ is big enough).

*Is this the correct weighting factor rsp. the correct way to find $\omega_0$?*

PS: I'm also thankful for anyone finding better tags for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem.

**Let's first generalize it and simplify the notation**.  There are two multinomial distributions, one with probabilities $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ = $(2/(n+1), 1/(n+1), \ldots, 1/(n+1))$ and the other with probabilities $(q_1,q_2, \ldots, q_n)$ = $(3/(2n+1), 2/(2n+1), \ldots, 2/(2n+1))$.  The probabilities are in descending order: $p_1 \ge p_2 \ge \cdots \ge p_n \gt 0$ and $q_1 \ge q_2 \ge \cdots \ge q_n \gt 0$.

You make $t$ independent observations of each, with counts $k_i$ and $m_i$ ($i=1, 2, \ldots, n$), respectively.  However, you do not know the subscripts: you only have the  ordered pairs $\left((k_{\sigma(1)},m_{\sigma(1)}), \ldots, (k_{\sigma(n)}, m_{\sigma(n)})\right)$ for some unknown permutation $\sigma$ of the subscripts.

You propose identifying which of these pairs corresponds to subscript $1$ by fixing positive coefficients $x$ and $y$ and computing the statistics

$$z_i = x k_i + y m_i, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n,$$

and nominating the subscript with the largest value of $z_i$.

Let's assume your loss function is simply the indicator of correctness, so that **your aim is to maximize the chance that $z_1$ is the largest of the $z_i$.**

To get a handle on what the optimal values of $x$ and $y$ ought to be, consider the case where both $n$ and $t$ are large.  Large $n$ allows us to ignore the slight dependency of the $k_i$ (and $m_i$), treating them as if they were independent.  Large $t$ allows us to adopt Normal approximations to the distributions of the $k_i$ and $m_i$.  These state that, to a good approximation,

$$k_i \sim N(p_i t, p_i(1-p_i)t); \quad m_i \sim N(q_i t, q_i(1-q_i)t)$$

(where the parameters are the mean and variance).  Therefore

$$z_i \sim N((x p_i + y q_i)t, (x^2 p_i(1-p_i) + y^2 q_i(1-q_i))t).$$

To maximize the chance of making a correct determination, we want to maximize the probability that $z_1 \gt z_i$ for $i \gt 1$.  Because

$$\eqalign{
z_1 - z_i \sim & N((x(p_1-p_i) + y(q_1-q_i))t, \\
&(x^2 [p_1(1-p_1) + p_i(1-p_i)] + y^2 [ q_1(1-q_1)+q_i(1-q_i)])t),
}$$

this is tantamount to maximizing the z-score,

$$z = \frac{(x(p_1-p_i) + y(q_1-q_i))t}{\sqrt{(x^2 [p_1(1-p_1) + p_i(1-p_i)] + y^2 [ q_1(1-q_1)+q_i(1-q_i)])t}}.$$

This expression takes the form

$$z = \sqrt{t} \frac{a x + b y}{\sqrt{c x^2 + d y^2}}$$

for *strictly positive* coefficients $a, b, c, d$ (guaranteeing $z$ will be positive, which should be obvious).  Note, too, that only the *ratio* $\xi = x/y$ matters, because rescaling $x$ and $y$ does not change the ordering of the $z_i$.  It therefore suffices to maximize the square of this expression,

$$z^2  = t \frac{(a\xi + b)^2}{c\xi^2 + d},$$

for $\xi \gt 0$.

This straightforward problem has the solution

$$\eqalign{
\xi = &\frac{a d}{b c} \\
    = &\frac{(p_1 - p_i)(q_1(1-q_1)+q_i(1-q_i)}{q_1 - q_i)(p_1(1-p_1) + p_i(1-p_i))} \\
    = &\frac{1/(n+1)(3(2n-2)/(2n+1)^2  + 2(2n-1)/(2n+1)^2)}{1/(2n+1)(2(n-1)/(n+1)^2 + n/(n+1)^2)} \\
    = & \frac{10 n^2 + 2 n - 8}{6 n^2 - n - 2}
}$$

for *all* $i \gt 1$.  Recalling the assumption that $n$ is large, we retain only the highest powers of $n$ and find (choosing $x=1$ so that $y = 1/\xi$):

$$x = 1, \quad y = 3/5 = 0.6.$$

**This literally answers the question**: the value $\log_2(3/2) \sim 0.585$ is not quite the right weight, although it's (surprisingly) close.

This analysis does not answer the more basic question, though: as a function of $n$ and $t$, what is the best weight?  This can be found with a similar analysis using much more painful calculations concerning the multinomial distribution in place of the Normal approximations.  I suspect, without any proof, that the formula for $\xi$ will work well even for small $n$ and small $t$.

[image: Plot of 1/xi vs. n]

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice answer! I assume that the graph - as there is no $t$ - is the solution for the approximation using the normal distribution and not the painful multinomial distribution. Is this correct?

Comment: I was also wondering if this approach (using a linear combination of both counts) is the correct one. What do you think (yes/no is enough)? Thanks, again.

Comment: @pul Yes, the graph simply shows $1/\xi$ using the formula for the Normal approximation.  I believe that a linear estimator has good properties in this case, but have not rigorously explored all the alternatives.  Clearly it will have some asymptotically optimal properties, but conceivably for small samples one could do slightly better with a well-designed nonlinear procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I'll stay with the linear estimator for now. By the way, I got this estimator and the value $\log_2{\frac{3}{2}}$ by maximum likeliness estimation.